# Несовместимые типы в методе

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть метод, который сохраняет объект, но при попытке сохранить его в методы появляется ошибка:

> saveIngredientRefs(long, java.util.List<com.example.pizzacloud.bind.IngredientRef>)' in 'com.example.pizzacloud.order.JdbcOrderRepository' cannot be applied to '(long, java.util.@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.validation.constraints.Size(min = 1, message = "You must choose at least 1 ingredient") List<com.example.pizzacloud.meal.Ingredient>)

мой pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PizzaCloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PizzaCloud</name>
    <description>PizzaCloud</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто: метод `saveIngredientRefs` принимает в качестве второго параметра `List<IngredientRef>`, но в коде в этот метод передается `List<Ingredient>`, полученный через вызов метода `getIngredients()` класса `Pizza`.

В ошибке, собственно, про это и говорится прямым текстом.
И IDE подчеркивает красным цветом место, где код не скомпилируется.

Видимо, нужно конвертировать список объектов `Ingredient` в список `IngredientRef` перед передачей списка в метод, например вот так:

```java
List<IngredientRef> ingredientRefs = pizza.getIngredients().stream()
        .map(ing -> new IngredientRef(ing.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
saveIngredientRefs(pizzaId, ingredientRefs);
```

Такую конвертацию списка можно также вынести в отдельный метод.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: надо бы глянуть код классов `Ingredient` и `IngredientRef` чтобы дать полный ответ, но в целом нужно вручную создать на каждый `Ingredient` новый объект типа `IngredientRef` и вручную смапить все поля одного класса в другой.

Comment: Я добавил скрин, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @AspireDeveloper я дополнил ответ